# Copy Constructors of classes instantiating derived classes

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

I have unsuccessfully been trying to create a copy constructor of a class that instantiates a derived class.

Let's say I have the following pure virtual class:

```
class AbstractBar{
public:
    virtual void printMe() = 0;

};
```

Class `Bar` inherits from `AbstractBar` as follows:

```
class Bar: public AbstractBar {
    std::string name_;

public:
    explicit Bar(std::string name) : name_ {std::move(name)}{};

    void printMe() override { std::cout << name_ << std::endl; }
};
```

My class `Foo` now attempts to make use of polymorphism by declaring a pointer to type `AbstractClass` as follows:

```
class Foo{
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBar> theBar_;

public:
    explicit Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar){
        theBar_ = std::move(bar);
    };

    void printBar(){
        theBar_->printMe();
    }
};
```

I do however want `Foo` to be copied so I add the following copy constructor:

```
    Foo(const Foo &other) {
        theBar_ = std::unique_ptr<AbstractBar>();
        *theBar_ = *(other.theBar_);
    }
```

And this is where it breaks.

What I gather is that this may be a problem since `theBar` in the copy constructor thinks it is pointing to an `AbstractBar` but when I try to copy the object it points to, in the next line, I actually give it a derived `Bar` class.

Is there a proper way to implement this copy constructor?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied, just moved

Comment: I suspect a covariant *clone* is about to be on the menu.

Comment: @MatG so then I assume creating a new `unique_ptr` and then attempting to copy the object that the previous one pointed to constitutes a `copy` in the realm of `unique_ptr`s?  It is then also true, I guess, that it will never be possible to create a copy of an object that contains a `unique_ptr` anywhere in it's definition, ie, there is now way to implement this copy constructor as is.

Comment: If you want to make your **Foo** class a semantically correct copyable class I'd suggest to use **std::shared_ptr** instead of **std::unique_ptr**. It's up to you do deciede whether it makes sense to allow copy of **Foo** and if it does, then use shared pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `std::unique_ptr<T>` is indeed unique. Therefore you cannot expect two things to point to the same instance-of-whatever by copying them. That said, I *think* what you're trying to do is *clone* whatever the "thing" is that is held by that member unique_ptr to allow a *deep* copy of a `Foo`.

If that is the case, you need a covariant *clone*. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct AbstractBar
{
    virtual ~AbstractBar() = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractBar> clone() = 0;
    virtual void printMe() = 0;
};

class Bar : public AbstractBar
{
    std::string name_;

public:
    explicit Bar(std::string name) : name_{std::move(name)} {};

    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBar> clone() override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Bar>(name_);
    }

    void printMe() override
    {
        std::cout << name_ << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBar> theBar_;

public:
    explicit Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar)
        : theBar_(std::move(bar))
    {
    }

    Foo(const Foo &other)
        : theBar_(other.theBar_->clone())
    {
    }

    void printBar()
    {
        theBar_->printMe();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(std::make_unique<Bar>("Some String"));
    Foo bar(foo);

    foo.printBar();
    bar.printBar();
}
```

Important: `foo` and `bar` will each have their own `Bar` instance via a unique pointer to the abstract base of `Bar`, namely `AbstractBar`. Hopefully that was the intent. This isn't the only way to do this, but it is probably the easiest to understand.

Comment: This solution is hurting my eyes, a LOT. Why is so hard to be semantically correct? Here you pretend that copying is not allowed but there is a hack to "break that contract". I believe that the proper way of doing this would be to use a shared pointer instead of unique pointer.

Comment: @Gabeeka - `shared_ptr` doesn't copy, the OP *does* want to copy. Introducing shared ownership is only "the proper way" if the pointee can indeed be shared. The OP gave no indication of that.